# ActionDispatch::Static in Rails production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actiondispatch

I'm looking to use `ActionDispatch::Static` to serve static files in a directory other than public. It works perfectly in development, but I can't seem to get the same results in production.

I have my static files in `/var/www/mysite.com-static`. In an initializer, I've added the following:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_after Rack::SendFile, ActionDispatch::Static, '/var/www/mysite.com-static'
```

The output of `rake middleware` is as follows:

```
use Raven::Rack
use Rack::Sendfile
use ActionDispatch::Static
use Rack::Lock
use #<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x00000005e61130>
use Rack::Runtime
...
```

Why do I get 404s on every page I request within /var/www/myapp.com-static?

Comment: If nginx serves your static assets, then why are you trying to handle it with help of rails app?

Comment: nginx serves my static assets in /var/www/myapp.com/public. I'd also like to serve static assets in /var/www/myapp.com-static. As far as I know, nginx only allows you to specify one root (without using a location).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem adding the middleware in my Rails app's `config.ru`.

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)

# Added the following line
use ActionDispatch::Static, '/var/www/myapp.com-static'

run Rails.application
```

This worked because I was setting the path for ActionDispatch::Static in an initializer that was loaded after the middleware was already mounted. If I had correctly configured my load order, `Rails.application.config.middleware` would have also worked.

Comment: That's very odd. While there are some differences between the two, not sure why adding ActionDispatch::Static in a different place would make a difference here.

Comment: Yes, I thought so too. The strangest part is that using config.middleware.use works fine in dev and test, but refused to work in production.

Comment: The obvious reason for this to work in dev but not production is if NGinX is trying to serve a file from the wrong place and can't. So since you're serving static files, that's not quite *as* weird :-)

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: The obvious failure mode for this would be if NGinX recognized the directory, tried to serve the file from a static dir, and served a 404 before your app got a chance to try.